# grid-template-columns: and rows: don't work. Netbeans says unknown property

Tags: css, netbeans

grid-template-columns: and rows: don't work. Netbeans says unknown property. why?grid-template-columns: and rows: don't work. Netbeans says unknown property. why?

Answer (score 3):

> grid-template-columns: and rows: don't work

They "don't work" within the NetBeans IDE, and the error messages are annoying, but your CSS that NetBeans is objecting to will still run in the browser.

> Netbeans says unknown property. why?

It's a NetBeans bug, and I raised a bug report for this issue almost a year ago.

See [Many missing values for code completion of the CSS display property](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-445):

```
[1] The problem with autocomplete for CSS is not confined to missing
values for the display property. For example, no grid-... properties
(e.g. grid-column-start) are suggested, nor is row-gap. The list of
valid CSS properties and values used by autocomplete needs to be
updated.

[2] If a CSS property is not suggested during auto-completion then its
valid use in CSS code will be incorrectly reported as an error (e.g.
"Unknown property grid-column-gap").

[3] A serious side effect of the previous issue is that genuine errors
in CSS code may be much harder to identify because they are mixed in
with bogus errors.
```

Unfortunately the issue is still open and unresolved.

Comment: That bug report is now considered ```resolved``` even though the IDE in CSS still does not recognise ```grid-template-columns``` (or ```grid-template-areas``` & ```grid-area```).